# Disable or delete Deepviews in Branch io

Tags: android, ios, branch.io

The problem is very simply, upon transition according to the link (generated with a brunch) on the iPhone (transition from the android and a desktop normal) appears an intermediate window (DeepView) as to disconnect it or to remove, someone faced such problem, in admin panel they can't be removed or disconnected or I simply didn't understand as it to make.

[image]

P.S I wrote to support but they don't hurry to answer
Maybe I not correctly generate the link, I disconnected all collateral parameters

```
BranchUniversalObject *branchUniversalObject = [[BranchUniversalObject alloc] initWithCanonicalIdentifier:@"item/12345"];
BranchLinkProperties *linkProperties = [[BranchLinkProperties alloc] init];
[branchUniversalObject getShortUrlWithLinkProperties:linkProperties andCallback:^(NSString *url, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"%@",url);
}];
```

**RESULT from support:** This is a known issue, and we're working on it - in the meantime, if you want to redirect to a custom desktop URL, you should expand the 'redirects' section when you are creating or editing a marketing link and put in the desired custom desktop URL. This will remove the Deepview. It may take a minute to propagate this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a couple things you can do here. First, you can try disabling the Deepview and saving your settings. If you're seeing a persistent value for $desktop_deepview, $ios_deepview, or $android_deepview in your marketing links deep link data section and if you want to redirect to a custom URL instead, you should expand the 'redirects' section when you are creating or editing a marketing link and put in the desired custom redirect URL. This will remove the Deepview. It may take a minute to propagate this change.

Comment: you should expand the 'redirects' section when you are creating or editing a marketing link and put in the desired custom redirect URL. This will remove the Deepview. It may take a minute to propagate this change - its work, thx.